# Enable USB Debugger on a phone with a broken screen

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen

I have done my research on how to enable the debugger, but most of them seem to be useless or missleading.

Now I do not need any backup, my phone is empty and I use that broken Samsung s6 for testing my apps etc.

I had USB Debugger on but I thought I will reset the phone and I did the factory reset (stupid me) and I assume USB debugger got disabled as I can not access my phone, nor Vysor is working for me.

Simple question, is it even possible to ENABLE debugger on a phone with a broken screen (cant controll or do anything with the phone)?

If the answer is yes, please provide any proper tutorials of how to use shell.

Comment: Have you considered flashing an alternative ROM that has debugging enabled out of the box? That might work if you can get to the bootloader and issue fastboot commands over usb.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will help, but anyway. If you could somehow execute following command on the phone, you should be able to just make it work:

`setprop persist.service.adb.enable 1`

This will enable USB debugging on the device and persist across reboots. The phone might need to be rooted.

Maybe connect a wireless keyboard and do some key combinations to reach command input. I have no idea how to do that though.

Comment: Many devices allow a keyboard or a mouse attached through USB OTG. This can be used for input. If the phone is broken in the sense of not showing anything, the accessibility features (screen reader) might help, and there's hopefully a way of activating that without seeing the screen